# C# Linq - group where multiple columns match?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to group items together where two or more fields match each other. I am not exactly sure how to accomplish this.

**Here's some example data**:

```
   TIME  |        TITLE            |   CHANNEL
---------+-------------------------+---------------
  10:00  |  Liverpool-Manchester   |   Viasat
  10:00  |  Liverpool-Manchester   |  Viasat HD
  10:00  |         Bla-debla       |  OtherChannel
  10:00  |        team1-team2      |  SomeChannel
  10:00  |        team1-team2      | SomeChannel HD
```

I want to group items where `TIME` and `TITLE` match. Like below.

**First grouped items:**

```
  10:00  |   Liverpool-Manchester   |  Viasat
  10:00  |   Liverpool-Manchester   | Viasat HD
```

**Second grouped items:**

```
  10:00  |   Bla-debla              |  OtherChannel
```

**Third grouped items:**

```
  10:00  |   team1-team2            | SomeChannel
  10:00  |   team1-team2            | SomeChannel HD
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Any two fields or only TIME and TITLE?

Comment: time and title must match on both rows.

Comment: Then you can use of the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following please:

`from c in collection
  group c.Title by new {c.Title,c.Time} into t
  where t.Count()>1
   select t;`

You will need to introduce new anonymous type if you want to group by more than one property and specify the properties in there

Not tested but should work.

Answer (score 4):

You can, using

```
group x by new { x.Time, x.Title}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your input is a `DataTable`.

```
var dataQ = from row in data.AsEnumerable()
    group row by new {
        time  = row.Field<DateTime>("time"),
        title = row.Field<String>("title")
    } into GrpTimeTitle
    select new {
        Time  = GrpTimeTitle.Key.time,
        Title = GrpTimeTitle.Key.title,
        Count = GrpTimeTitle.Count(),
        FirstChannel = GrpTimeTitle.First().Field<String>("channel")
    };
```

Comment: as you already use linq to dataset, you could use DataRow's Field extension method.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: +1 Looks like your solution also introduces a group identifier with `GrpTimeTitle.Count()` which should aid the OP with enumerating over the distinct groups? Is that correct?

Comment: @VC 74: You are right, corrected. @Paul: The query groups already by `time`and `title`,I've added the `Count` only to tell him how to get the record count for every group.

Comment: Will this also give me the Channel value?

Comment: @user: Yes, it's part of the `IEnumerable<DataRow>` in the `Rows` property. You can for example select `Rows.First().Field<String>("Channel")` to get the first.

Comment: Is it possible to accomplish this without a DataTable? In my cause i have a IQueryable<MyOWnModel>.

Comment: The way is the same for a IQueryable<whatever>.

Comment: @VC 74: I must admit that i've not understood the benefit of using the `Field` extensions instead of casting it. The extensions must also cast implicitely.

Comment: @TimSchmelter In case of a null value, Field will return a value which is much more linq compliant than DbNull.Value

Comment: Allright. How would I go about getting this data to a view in my MVC3 website and outputting it? :P

Comment: @user603037: I guess that would be another question.